# How to get data from List in JSTL with autocomplete spring mvc

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, spring-mvc, jstl

I'm using JSTL and Jquery to get data into autocomplete, list of data will get from List in Spring mvc

My action:

```
List<Map> mapList = googleMapLocationService.getAllGoogleMapLocations();
model.put("mapList", mapList);
```

jquery/jsp:

```
<script>
  $( function() {
  var availableTags =
      <c:forEach items="${mapList}" var="map">
      [         
          "<c:out value="${map.address}"/>"         
      ];
      </c:forEach>
  $( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
    source: availableTags
  });
 } );
```

```
  <div style="width:320px ;margin-left: -38px; margin-top: -24px">
    <input id="tags" path="tags" />
  </div>
```

UPDATED: (try to replace 'address' is 'id')

```
<script>
$( function() {
var availableTags = []
    <c:forEach items="${mapList}" var="map">
        availableTags.push("<c:out value="'${map.id}', "/>");
    </c:forEach>
 $( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
   source: availableTags
 });
} );
```

RESULT:

[image]

When I type a 'keyword' any, it seem can not list on autocomplete

How can I fix the problem ? Thank so much !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code generates the javascript array structure. Try checking this.

```
 <script>
  $( function() {
  var availableTags =
      <c:forEach items="${mapList}" var="map" varStatus="totalCount">
      [         
          <c:out value="'${map.address}'">
          </c:out>
          <c:if test="${totalCount.count lt fn:length(mapList)}">
          <c:out value=",">
          </c:out>
          </c:if>      
      ];
      </c:forEach>
  $( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
    source: availableTags
  });
 } );
```

Comment: i have modified the code. as an array it should possess array structure but in your scenario there is no comma and quotation to describe the array. just try this. but your last value also ends with comma you have to restrict it using finding length and prevent it from displaying.

Comment: Hi @ram vinoth: I have updated result as above, your first code is seem correct, I try to change 'address' by 'id' and can get data, however value of autocomplate is incorrect

Comment: try the second one hope this will give you the result what you expect